# java application doing frequent major GCs though xmx is yet to reach

Tags: java, garbage-collection

My application is doing frequent Major GCs after a restart and both Minor and Major GCs are happening more frequently as well as the GC times have increased significantly especially the minor GC times. I'm unable to understand why this is happening. Even though the xmx (40GB) is way more than the current consumption (12GB to 28GB) the GCs are happening more frequently. Please guide me on what could be going wrong. There was a memory leak and I fixed it but now this is something I really don't understand.

Before restart:
[image]
[image]

After restart:
[image]
[image] Following are the JAVA_OPTIONS:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_362"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_362-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.362-b08, mixed mode)
```

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/logs/heap_dump.bin -XX:InitialHeapSize=268435456 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:MaxHeapSize=42949672960 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Please find the GC logs here - https://github.com/kprateek777/gc

Comment: GC is totally dependent on your JVM. You have no control on this.

Comment: Maybe there is another memory leak.  Maybe your application is simply generating excessive garbage.  (And when you say *"... way more than ..."*, can you be more precise?)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "going wrong"? What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: Don't link to information in a git repo like that.  As soon as you delete the repo containing the logs, your question makes no sense.  Information that is relevant to the question should be >in the question<.

Comment: Added more information to the question @StephenC

Comment: After briefly scanning the logs, I don't think there is anything "wrong" here.  This *appears to be* a simple case of an application generating a lot of garbage.  That leads to lots of young gen GCs and occasional old gen GCs to deal with tenured objects.  If you want to fix this:  1) look for more storage leaks, 2) look for ways (i.e. application algorithm changes) to reduce the rate of garbage generation and 3) look for ways to reduce the total amount / number of reachable (non-leaking) objects.

Comment: @StephenC the amount of garbage per second after the restart is not more than before. If you look closely in the GC log before restart the young gen sizes are bigger before a minor GC whereas they are happening at smaller sizes and taking more time later. This is my worry. I worked on this application for the past year trying to reduce the garbage and this is the best till date. Unfortunately it is turning out to be too expensive in terms of garbage and resource consumption

Comment: @StephenC my worry is that the GCs will start happening all the time after some time rendering the app unresponsive. This is what happens when there is a mem leak but a mem leak makes the old gen grow which I don’t see here.

Comment: There is not enough information on what precisely you have changed.  For instance, you must have done something to cause 1) the new space to be smaller and 2) more objects to be retained in the old space.  As to your broader problem, we can't advise you how to tune an application based on zero information about the application, what it does, and how it is implemented.  My advice would be to hire a consultant ...

Comment: But if you are *actually* worrying about response times, try switching to G1GC or maybe ZGC; i.e. a low pause GC.

Comment: @StephenC Hiring a consultant is going to pretty difficult. I did try G1GC with defaults and it led to frequent GCs. The eden space was not growing enough (~2GB) leading to frequent GCs and also the old gen kept stable. This led to the slowdown of the app. I then tried the following params  as suggested as basic tuning on Redhat's GC guide and I saw increase eden and old gen but the performance of the app is still not up to the mark. I will keep you posted

Comment: @StephenC (-Xms40960m -Xmx40960m -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UseG1GC -Dinactivity.days.to.expiry=60 -agentpath:/dasd/share/yourkit-2021.3-b231/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so=port=10001,listen=all,telemetrylimit=1 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/logs/ade_gc.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/logs/heap_dump.bin -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=20 -XX:ConcGCThreads=5 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70)

Comment: Frequent GCs is not the real problem.  The problem you are trying to avoid is long or uneven response times.  But if the long responses are actually due to your application generating too much garbage, then GC tuning is not going to help.  You need to fix the application.  Or get faster hardware.

Comment: *"Hiring a consultant is going to pretty difficult"* - The flip side is that spending another a year trying to get your application to go faster will also be pretty difficult ... to explain to your boss or client or whoever is waiting for your project completion. (I assume you are doing this because the application's performance actually matters ... to them.)